# Highcharts don't render in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sharepoint, highcharts, sharepoint-2010

I am making a dashboard in a Sharepoint html page. My charts render and display correctly in Chrome, but only the pie chart renders in Internet Explorer 11. If I create a static array of data for the series, it works. If I try to populate it dynamically, it only works in the pie chart.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {


    Date.dateDiff = function(datepart, fromdate, todate) {
        datepart = datepart.toLowerCase();
        var diff = todate - fromdate;
        var divideBy = {
            w: 604800000,
            d: 86400000,
            h: 3600000,
            n: 60000,
            s: 1000
        };

        return Math.floor(diff / divideBy[datepart]);
    }

    function businessWeekDifference(startDate, endDate) {

        // Validate input
        if (endDate < startDate)
            return 0;

        var diff = Date.dateDiff('d', startDate, endDate);
        var days = diff;

        // Subtract two weekend days for every week in between
        var weeks = Math.floor(days / 7);
        days = days - (weeks * 2);

        // Handle special cases
        var startDay = startDate.getDay();
        var endDay = endDate.getDay();

        // Remove weekend not previously removed.   
        if (startDay - endDay > 1)
            days = days - 2;

        // Remove start day if span starts on Sunday but ends before Saturday
        if (startDay == 0 && endDay != 6) {
            days = days - 1;
        }

        // Remove end day if span ends on Saturday but starts after Sunday
        if (endDay == 6 && startDay != 0) {
            days = days - 1;
        }

        return days;
    }

    function average(arr) {
        return _.reduce(arr, function(memo, num) {
            return memo + num;
        }, 0) / (arr.length === 0 ? 1 : arr.length);
    }


    function translateMonth(d) {
        var month;
        if (d.getMonth() === 0) {
            month = 'Jan';
        } else if (d.getMonth() === 1) {
            month = 'Feb';
        } else if (d.getMonth() === 2) {
            month = 'Mar';
        } else if (d.getMonth() === 3) {
            month = 'Apr';
        } else if (d.getMonth() === 4) {
            month = 'May';
        } else if (d.getMonth() === 5) {
            month = 'Jun';
        } else if (d.getMonth() === 6) {
            month = 'Jul';
        } else if (d.getMonth() === 7) {
            month = 'Aug';
        } else if (d.getMonth() === 8) {
            month = 'Sep';
        } else if (d.getMonth() === 9) {
            month = 'Oct';
        } else if (d.getMonth() === 10) {
            month = 'Nov';
        } else if (d.getMonth() === 11) {
            month = 'Dec';
        }
        return month;
    }

    function generateX(comp, tbs, sched) {
        var xAxis = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < comp.length; i++) {
            var n = comp[i].name;
            xAxis.push(n);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < tbs.length; i++) {
            var n2 = tbs[i].name;
            xAxis.push(n2);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < sched.length; i++) {
            var n3 = sched[i].name;
            xAxis.push(n3);
        }
        return xAxis;
    }


    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Initial_x0020_Contact_x0020_Date' Ascending='True'/><FieldRef Name='Date' Ascending='True'/><FieldRef Name='Date_x0020_Session_x0020_Schedul' Ascending='True'/><FieldRef Name='Session_x0020_Completion_x0020_D' Ascending='True'/><FieldRef Name='Business_x0020_Unit'/><FieldRef Name='Session_x0020_Status'/></OrderBy></Query>",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Initial_x0020_Contact_x0020_Date'/><FieldRef Name='Date'/><FieldRef Name='Date_x0020_Session_x0020_Schedul'/><FieldRef Name='Session_x0020_Completion_x0020_D'/><FieldRef Name='Business_x0020_Unit'/><FieldRef Name='Session_x0020_Status'/></ViewFields>",
        listName: "{C6673173-9AC5-4A6B-9401-15D0F38EFCB8}",
        completefunc: function(xData, status) {

                var diff1 = [];
                var diff2 = [];
                var diff3 = [];
                var spc1Data = [];
                var toBeSchedStatsData = [];
                var schedStatsData = [];
                var completedStatsData = [];
                var canceledStatsData = [];


                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                    var bu = $(this).attr('ows_Business_x0020_Unit');
                    var ic = new Date($(this).attr('ows_Initial_x0020_Contact_x0020_Date'));
                    var as = new Date($(this).attr('ows_Date_x0020_Session_x0020_Schedul'));
                    var sc = new Date($(this).attr('ows_Session_x0020_Completion_x0020_D'));
                    var d = new Date($(this).attr('ows_Date'));
                    var status = $(this).attr('ows_Session_x0020_Status');
                    var month;
                    var difference1;
                    var difference2;
                    var difference3;
                    var isDate = function(date) {
                        return ((new Date(date) !== "Invalid Date" && !isNaN(new Date(date))));
                    }


                    //YTD Requests by ATO data
                    if (bu === "Global Connections Management"){ 
                        spc1Data.push({
                            BU: "GCM"
                        });
                    }else if(bu === "Technology Design & Architecture"){
                         spc1Data.push({
                            BU: "TD&A"
                        });
                    }else if(bu === "Global Customer Service"){
                         spc1Data.push({
                            BU: "GCS"
                        });
                    }else{
                         spc1Data.push({
                            BU: bu
                        });
                    }

                    if (isDate(d)) {

                        //Coaching Request Volume data
                        if (status === "To be Scheduled" && !isDate(ic)) {
                            month = translateMonth(d);
                            toBeSchedStatsData.push({
                                status: status,
                                date: month
                            });
                        }
                        if (status === "Canceled" || status === "No Show") {
                            if (!isDate(as)) {
                                month = translateMonth(ic);
                                canceledStatsData.push({
                                    status: status,
                                    date: month
                                });
                            } else {
                                month = translateMonth(as);
                                canceledStatsData.push({
                                    status: status,
                                    date: month
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        if (isDate(ic)) {

                            //YTD Requests by ATO data
                            difference1 = businessWeekDifference(d, ic);
                            month = translateMonth(ic);
                            diff1.push({
                                name: month,
                                y: difference1
                            });
                            //Coaching Request Volume data
                            if (status === "To be Scheduled") {
                                month = translateMonth(ic);
                                toBeSchedStatsData.push({
                                    status: status,
                                    date: month
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        if (isDate(as)) {

                            //YTD Requests by ATO data
                            difference2 = businessWeekDifference(d, as);
                            month = translateMonth(as);
                            diff2.push({
                                name: month,
                                y: difference2
                            });

                            //Coaching Request Volume data
                            if (status === "Scheduled") {
                                month = translateMonth(as);
                                schedStatsData.push({
                                    status: status,
                                    date: month
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        if (isDate(sc)) {
                            //YTD Requests by ATO data
                            difference3 = businessWeekDifference(d, sc);
                            month = translateMonth(sc);
                            diff3.push({
                                name: month,
                                y: difference3
                            });

                            //Coaching Request Volume data       
                            if (status === "Completed") {
                                month = translateMonth(sc);
                                completedStatsData.push({
                                    status: status,
                                    date: month
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                /***********************************************************************************
                 *              Coaching Request Volume Stacked Bar Chart                                           *
                 ************************************************************************************/
                var counts1 = _.countBy(toBeSchedStatsData, 'date');
                var tbsData = _.map(counts1, function(value, key) {
                    return {
                        name: key,
                        y: value
                    };
                });

                //Scheduled 
                var counts2 = _.countBy(schedStatsData, 'date');
                var schedData = _.map(counts2, function(value, key) {
                    return {
                        name: key,
                        y: value
                    };
                });

                //Completed 
                var counts3 = _.countBy(completedStatsData, 'date');
                var compData = _.map(counts3, function(value, key) {
                    return {
                        name: key,
                        y: value
                    };
                });

                //Canceled
                var counts4 = _.countBy(canceledStatsData, 'date');
                var cancData = _.map(counts4, function(value, key) {
                    return {
                        name: key,
                        y: value
                    };
                });

                function verifyDataCount(arr1, comp) {
                    if (arr1.length < comp.length) {
                        var n = comp[0].name;
                        var add_object = {
                            "name": n,
                            "y": 0
                        };
                        arr1.splice(0, 0, add_object);
                    }
                }
                verifyDataCount(tbsData, compData);
                verifyDataCount(schedData, compData);
                verifyDataCount(cancData, compData);

                var tbsOutput = _.pluck(tbsData, "y");
                var cancOutput = _.pluck(cancData, "y");
                var schedOutput = _.pluck(schedData, "y");
                var compOutput = _.pluck(compData, "y");


                console.log(tbsOutput);
                //Draw Chart
                var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column',
                        options3d: {
                            enabled: false,
                            alpha: 5,
                            beta: 5,
                            viewDistance: 25,
                            depth: 40
                        },
                        renderTo: 'buRequestsStack',
                        marginTop: 80,
                        marginRight: 40,
                        plotBorderColor: '#0574AC',
                        borderWidth: .5,
                        plotShadow: true

                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Coaching Request Volume'
                    },
                    legend: {
                        itemStyle: {
                            color: '#868686',
                            fontSize: '10px',
                            fontWeight: 'medium'
                        }
                    },

                    xAxis: {
                        categories: generateX(compData, tbsData, schedData)
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        allowDecimals: false,
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Number of Requests'
                        }
                    },

                    tooltip: {
                        headerFormat: '<b>{point.key}</b><br>',
                        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: {point.y}' + ' {point.percentage:1.0f}%'
                    },

                    plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                            stacking: 'normal',
                            depth: 40
                        }
                    },

                    series: [{
                        name: 'To be Scheduled',
                        data: tbsOutput
                    }, {
                        name: 'Scheduled',
                        data: schedOutput
                    }, {
                        name: 'Completed',
                        data: compOutput
                    }, {
                        name: 'Canceled',
                        data: cancOutput
                    }]
                });

                /***********************************************************************************
                 *              YTD Requests by ATO Pie Chart                                           *
                 ************************************************************************************/
                var spcData = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < spc1Data.length; i++) {
                    if (String(spc1Data[i].BU).indexOf('-') > -1) {
                        var bu = String(spc1Data[i].BU);
                        spc1Data[i].BU = bu.slice(0, 8);
                        spcData[i] = spc1Data[i];
                    } else {
                        spcData[i] = spc1Data[i];
                    }
                }
                var chartData = [];
                var buData = _.groupBy(spcData, 'BU');
                _.each(buData, function(row) {
                    var buCount = row.length;
                    chartData.push({
                        name: row[0].BU,
                        y: buCount,
                        drilldown: row[0].BU
                    });
                });


                var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'pie',
                        plotBorderColor: '#0574AC',
                        borderWidth: .5,
                        plotShadow: true,
                        options3d: {
                            enabled: true,
                            alpha: 55,
                            beta: 0
                        },
                        renderTo: 'buRequests',
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'YTD Requests by ATO'
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '{point.y}' + ' Requests' + '<br>' + '{point.percentage:1.0f}%'
                            //percentageDecimals: 1
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            allowPointSelect: true,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            depth: 35,
                            dataLabels: {
                                distance: 1,
                                useHTML: true,
                                enabled: true,
                                fontWeight: 'medium',
                                //format: '{point.name}'+ '<br>' + '{point.y}' +' Requests' + '<br>' + '{point.percentage:1.0f}%',
                                formatter: function() {
                                    var req;
                                    if (this.point.y === 1) {
                                        req = " Request";
                                    } else {
                                        req = " Requests";
                                    }

                                    return '<span style="color:' + this.point.color + '">' + this.point.name + '<br>' + this.point.y + req + '<br>' + Math.round(this.percentage) + '%' + '</span>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        type: 'pie',
                        name: 'BU Count',
                        data: chartData
                    }],
                                   });

                /***********************************************************************************
                 *              Coaching Request Cycle Time Line Chart                                          *
                 ************************************************************************************/
                var chartData1 = [];
                chartData1 = _.chain(diff1)
                    .groupBy("name")
                    .map(function(value, key) {
                        return {
                            name: key,
                            y: Math.round(average(_.pluck(value, "y")))
                        }
                    })
                    .value();

                var chartData2 = [];
                chartData2 = _.chain(diff2)
                    .groupBy("name")
                    .map(function(value, key) {
                        return {
                            name: key,
                            y: Math.round(average(_.pluck(value, "y")))
                        }
                    })
                    .value();

                var chartData3 = [];
                chartData3 = _.chain(diff3)
                    .groupBy("name")
                    .map(function(value, key) {
                        return {
                            name: key,
                            y: Math.round(average(_.pluck(value, "y")))
                        }
                    })
                    .value();

                var chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'line',
                        renderTo: 'buRequestsLine',
                        plotBorderColor: '#0574AC',
                        borderWidth: .5,
                        plotShadow: true
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Coaching Request Cycle Time',
                        style: {
                            color: '#666666',
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        itemStyle: {
                            color: '#868686',
                            fontSize: '10px',
                           fontWeight: 'medium'
                        }
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: _.pluck(chartData3, name),

                        labels: {
                            //enabled: true,
                            formatter: function() {
                                return this.value;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        allowDecimals: false,
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Average # of Business Days',
                            style: {
                                color: '#666666'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        //pointFormat: '{point.y}' + ' Days',
                        //formatter: function() {
                        //return 'The value for <b>' + point.y + '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>, in series '+ this.series.name;
                        //},
                        shared: false,
                        crosshairs: true
                            //percentageDecimals: 1
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        //type: 'line',
                        name: 'Initial Contact',
                        data: chartData1,
                        color: '#EF6F00'
                    }, {
                        //type: 'line',
                        name: 'Appt Scheduled',
                        data: chartData2,
                        color: '#4CA90C'
                    }, {
                        //type: 'line',
                        name: 'Coaching Completed',
                        data: chartData3,
                        color: '#0574AC'
                    }]
                });

            } //finalFunct
    }); //end .SPServices2       
});//end doc
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: There are no errors in the console.

Comment: @KevinSimple SharePoint forces Internet Explorer capability in organizations as very few don't use it exclusively.

Comment: @ElvisLikeBear: that's sad..

Comment: @KevinSimple Well reality is it's still the dominant browser in the market. Not supporting it is never not an option for anybody who cares about their customer.

Comment: @ElvisLikeBear: honestly, i am a .net developer, i think ie is good, it's just not following the standars which other browser does, i think it's just got a little bit pride

Comment: @KevinSimple Oh don't get me wrong, I hate IE as well. It's terrible and causes so many problems. I just think he has no choice but to support it (sucks!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date that Microsoft SharePoint passes in is seen as invalid by the JavaScript running in Microsoft Internet Explorer. I brought the date in as a string, parsed it, and pushed it to a JavaScript date object and everything works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `console.log()` line. In Internet Explorer the console is only available when the debugger is opened and an error is thrown if it is not.

Replace `console.log(tbsOutput);` with `alert(tbsOutput);` and it should then work as expected.

Comment: I tried changing the console.log to alert and it did not fix the issue.  I thought maybe it was a formatting issue and tried to cast the data to an int and that didn't work , then I used var tbsOutput = _.pluck(tbsData, "y"); for the series data and that didn't work in IE either (but it did in Chrome). I'm at a loss as to what to do next.

Comment: I put alert(chart.series[0].data); after the chart and it is blank in IE. It's as if the chart is rendering before the data structure is populated.