# Highcharts programmed in for ASP.net webform (server control) are not displaying in internet explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, highcharts, webforms

I have put a highchart control in my aspx page. The control assigns the asp:Literal the Html string generated by high charts as shown below:

```
HighsoftNamespace Highsoft = new HighsoftNamespace();
string result = Highsoft.GetHighcharts(this.HighChart, 
this.ChartName).ToHtmlString(); 
this.litHighChartIncident.Text = result;
```

The chrome shows the chart perefctly without any errors but internet explorer throws the following error and does not display the chart:

Highcharts error #27: [www.highcharts.com/errors/27]

Internet explorer version is 11.

Any ideas what am i missing?

Comment: Refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443139/highcharts-dont-render-in-internet-explorer-11

Comment: I am using the static demo data in my highcharts and not populating them with dynamically assigned date values as mentioned in the share point example issue. Infact I am using hardcoded just the string values on x-axis and  double values on y-axis.  The high charts are showing well on chrome, firefox, safari and edge but throwing javascript errors in IE11.

Comment: You can try to use Highcharts script adjusted to older versions of IE: `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/oldie.js"></script>`